# Retrieve database structure

Tags: .net, sql-server, database

Can I retrieve full database structure using its connection string as collection of tables, its columns, relationships, etc?
Can I modify database using these objects?
**Edit:** Database - MS SQL Server. I need to be able to retrieve and edit database tables, column names, types, etc in code.

Comment: You need to give us a bit more detail.  What kind of database are you using.  How far have you got on your own etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [DbConnection.GetSchema()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y53he2tz.aspx) , see [here](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/01/15/2734.aspx) for a little tutorial.